# How to submit a collection via an html button

Tags: meteor

I have an html button. I want to insert a collection when it is clicked. How do I do this? I know how to do it from the console, but not the page. I'm using the basic hello world example at the moment.

Below is my code

```
var savedState = new Meteor.Collection("SavedState");

 Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {

    savedState.insert({Category:"SYNTHS", items: [{Name:"whatever"}]});

    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you getting? The code you have written works, assuming the code you have written around it is correct. See below.

Javascript:

```
var savedState = new Meteor.Collection("SavedState");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.events({
        'click input' : function () {
            savedState.insert({Category:"SYNTHS", items: [{Name:"whatever"}]});
        }
    });
}
```

Template:

```
<body>
    {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
    <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

Comment: Actually you're right, my code did work. I was confused as to how to verify it that's all. savedState.find({}).count();  But as a side note I'm wondering what the significance of putting it in the isClient block as to outside of it. Both seem to work.

Comment: If you place the insert outside of isClient it will be run on both the client and the server. You generally don't want that. In fact I'm can't think of an example of when you would want that. If the client does an insert the server will hear about it, and if the client has permission (which it does in Hello World because autopublish is on) the server will allow it. And vice versa: if the server does an insert and the client is subscribed the data will find its way into the client collection. Forcing the insert on both ends is possible, sure, but it is not particularly useful afaik.

Comment: You'd put a `new Meteor.Collection` outside because you want it to run both on the server and the client. That's the best example of why you'd want to put code outside of isClient/isServer